# JavaScript - Select string between specific word and next specific character on custom condition

Tags: javascript, string

I have a very long CSS code in a variable and I want to find the last matching condition in that.
My code is:

```
var str = 'body { background: #fff; } .customClass{ font-size: 12px; } .anotherClass { color: #292929 } body { color : #fff }';
var str2 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("body {") + 1, str.lastIndexOf("}"));
console.log(str2);
```

Here, I've shortened str for better understanding. In my case, it's around 100-200 lines minimum.

Now I only want the last `body { anything here }` substring. In above Eg. I want `body {color: #fff }` and not the first or any other occurrence of the body tag in the string. I know multiple body styling is not good code, but right now this code is dependent on a third party plugin. How can I do that?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/76981/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```js
var str = 'body { background: #fff; } .customClass{ font-size: 12px; } .anotherClass { color: #292929 } body { color : #fff } body{cool}';
var regex = /body\s+\{([^}]+)/g;
var temp;
var resultArray = [];
while ((temp = regex.exec(str)) != null)  
{  
resultArray.push(temp[1]);
} 
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are almost right with a little confusion about [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
var str = 'body { background: #fff; } .customClass{ font-size: 12px; } .anotherClass { color: #292929 } body { color : #fff }';
var str2 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("body {"), str.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
console.log(str2);
```

Comment: Hey, what if I have more CSS code after `}`. This code selects string after the closing brace of the body tag until the last occurence of `}`. I just want to select nextIndexOf `}`. Is it possible? Also what for the same condition for the first occurrence of `body{styles}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a small change in your str2

```
var str2 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("body"));
```

This will result the str2 as `body {color: #fff }` and if you need only the style part, add the following line too.

```
var styleStr = str2.substring(str2.indexOf('{')+1, str2.indexOf('}'));
```

Now it will result a string like `color : #fff`